# android - should ProgressDialog be checked for null before dismissed?

Tags: android, dialog, null, progress, dismiss

If I use `ProgressDialog.show()` on main which does call 2 AsyncTask. AsyncTask A and AsyncTask B may finish in undetermined order so I put `ProgressDialog.dismiss()` in onPostExecute in both AsyncTask.

The question is should I check for null value in both AsyncTask before dismissing the dialog?

```
if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){ progressDialog.dismiss(); }
```

OR just:

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

I don't know if ProgressDialog.dismiss() will handle this for me or it will throw NullPointerException if I don't check for null value before dismissing.

Comment: A ProgressDialog cannot set itself to null. So, you might be doing it somewhere.

Comment: @Tim, I thought that .dismiss() will destroy the instance. Maybe I was wrong. So if it's like what you've said. Calling .dismiss() multiple times even it was dismissed should not cause a problem like NullPointerException or crash an application?

Comment: No, calling dismiss() multiple times should not crash or throw NPE.

Answer (score 0):

java says this is always good to check for null . but you must`progressDialog.isShowing()` 
otherwise you can get a leak window exception sometime.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to check isShowing() because it is internally handled.
No need to handle it explicitly.